# How can Python's zeep module work against an API manager?

Tags: soap, zeep, gravitee

I've used zeep against a SOAP-service, and it works perfectly. However, when this service is placed behind Gravitee API Manager, I'm unable to get it to work any longer, just get a 404 response.

Here's my code :

```
from zeep import Client, Settings
import base64,sys, logging, traceback
from requests import Session
from zeep.transports import Transport
import requests
from lxml import etree

wsdl= 'https://link_to_service_on_gravitee'

session = Session()
session.verify = False
session.headers['Api-Key']= 'xxxxx'

transport = Transport(session=session)
settings = Settings(raw_response=True, strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client(wsdl, transport=transport, settings=settings)

data = []
data.append(
    {'ServerProcessId': 'GL07',
    'OrderNumber': 1}
     )

cdata = []
cdata.append(
    {'Username': 'xxx',
     'Client': 'yyy',
     'Password': 'zzz'}
     )  

node = client.create_message(client.service, 'GetResult',input=data, credentials=cdata)
print('*** SOAP Message')
print(etree.tostring(node))
print('*** End SOAP Message')


response = requests.Response()
try:     
   response = client.service.GetResult(input=data, credentials=cdata)
   print(response)
except Exception as e:
   print(response.headers)
   logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

When I test the message generated by Python (etree.tostring(node)) in SOAPUI, it works correctly. Also, if I alter the api-key, I get an error about authentication problems, so Gravitee seems to accept the key from my code.
But the response I get, with correct api-key, is always [404].

Got it to work when I downloaded the wsdl to a local file, but don't want to do this for every wsdl.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for getting a 404 from Gravitee:
* Did you create an API
* Did you create a simple plan for this API
* Did you deploy the API to the gateway.

Once all those steps are done, you should be able to consume your API.

Hope it helps,

Regards,